# ECS EC2 Launch Type: Service database connection string

Tags: mysql, docker, amazon-ecs, service-discovery

I am trying out a small POC (learning experiment) on docker.  I have 3  docker images, one each for a storefront, a search engine and a database engine called, storefront, solr, docmysql respectively. I have tried running them in a docker swarm (on a single node) on ec2 and it works fine.

In the POC, I next needed to move this to AWS ECS using the EC2 launch type on a single Non-Amazon ECS-Optimized AMI. I have installed and started a ecs-agent on this. I have created 3 services with one task  for each of the 3 images configured as containers within the task.  The question is about connecting to the database from the storefront.

The storefront has a property file where the database connection is typically defined as

```
  "jdbc:mysql://docmysql/hybris64?useConfigs=maxPerformance&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false".
```

This worked when I ran it as a docker swarm. Once I moved it to ECS (EC2 launch type), I had to expose the port 3306 from my task/container for the docmysql service. This gave me a service endpoint of docmysql.local, with 'local' being a private namespace. I tried changing the connection string to

```
"jdbc:mysql://docmysql.local/hybris64?useConfigs=maxPerformance&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false"
```

in the property file and it always fails with " Name or service not known". What should my connection string be? When the service is created I see 2 entries in Route 53, one SRV record and a A record. The A record has as its name a .docmysql.local, If I use this in the database connection string, I see that it works but obvious not the right thing to do with the hadcoded taskid. I have read about AWS Cloud Map (servicediscovery) but still not very clear how to go about it. I will not be putting any loadbalancer in front of my DB task in the service, there will always be only one task for the db.

So what is the best way to generate the connection string that works. Also why did I not have issues when I ran it as a docker swarm.

I know I can use an RDS instead of stating my own database, I will try that but for now need this working as I have started with this. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've raised some points before my own solution within the problem:

- Do you need your instance to scale using ECS? If not, migrate it to RDS.
- Do you need to deploy it on EC2-Type? If not, use fargate, it is more simple to handle.

Now, I've faced that issue on Fargate, and discovered that depending on your container/task definitions, it can be used inside the same task for testing purposes, so, 127.0.0.1 should be the answer.

On different tasks you need to work with awsvpc network mode so, you will have this:

- Each task that uses the awsvpc network mode receives its own elastic network interface, which is attached to the container instance that hosts it. (FROM AWS)

My suggestion is to create a Lambda Function to discover your network interface dynamically.

Read this for deeply understanding:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking.html

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/invoking-aws-lambda-functions-from-java/

Comment: Thanks. I did need it working only as EC2 Launch type as the POC/experiment was specifically for that. But since the time I posted the question I did a couple of things in line with what you say above. One, I tried Fargate but did not progress as it is stateless, while the DB can be RDS, the search (for the index) and the storefront (for media files, secrets etc) need access to files which are typically mounted into the container from the instance & I could not use mounts.

Comment: A second approach I tried was to put all the three containers in the same Task and created links between them and this worked but I do not want all three of them scaling in the same fashion so this was also not workable for me. The other option left is to use EKS. I will read the links you mention above and update here if I make any progress on this.

Comment: Oh, really nice of you to workout on different paths. Hope that you can achieve your goal. Make a try in Lambda, in AWS almost everything you can do with Lambda, I think that you may have to think a little, but it is possible. Update here and maybe I can help you further.

Comment: Another thing is setup the answer, you can post your answer here if you want, or mark me as the one. But, it is nice for everyone see that the question was solved.

Comment: ok,  I did put it as the question was about EC2 launch type and that did not work. I intend trying that again sometime. But if you think the other approaches can be considered as answers the I can mark yours as the answer. Let me know.

Comment: Hi, in my opinion, I think my answer is one of the many answers that exists for your case, and I think too that it's not the best one, it must have some easier way of doing it. So, you can mark it as the answer and when you solved the problem you put your resolution here, if you followed anything related to it. That would be great!